# Find the inner and outermorphisms of a particular dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Given that |Inn($D_8$)| = 8 and |Out($D_8$)| = 2 where Out($D_8$) = Aut($D_8$)/Inn($D_8$) and $D_8$ = {e,r,$r^2$,..,$r^7$,s,sr,...,$sr^7$} we want to find Inn($D_8$) and Out($D_8$).

We know that Out($D_8$) is a cyclic group (prime order) and we can let

Out($D_8$) = {f Inn($D_8$):$f \in $Aut($D_8$)}. We kow the identity element must be in Out($D_8$) and also another element of order 2. I get stuck here and not sure how to proceed to find Inn($D_8$) and Out($D_8$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** There is always a surjective homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Inn}(G)$ given by sending $g$ to conjugation by $g$.  If you figure out the kernel, $K$, of this homomorphism then $\mathrm{Inn}(D_8) \simeq D_8/K$ and $D_8/K$ will be pretty easy to understand.

For "finding" $\mathrm{Out}(D_8)$, if you are given that it has order $2$ then you know that it's the group $\mathbb Z/2$.  Is there something else you need to find?

Comment: Perhaps he wants an actual representative for the non-trivial coset of Out.

Comment: @Jim Could you justify how we know Out($D_8$) is Z/2? Like I understand both are cyclic and have order 2, we could say they are isomorphic, but how can we say they "equal".

Comment: @user77404 In this case "is" means isomorphic.  They are not strictly equal.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. Your saying we can find the isomorphisms of Inn($D_8$) and Out($D_8$) which I understand from your answer. But if we wanted to find these sets explicitly that would be a bit harder?

Comment: Not too much harder.  The elements of $D_8/K$ are cosets of $K$.  Once you know what they are let $\{x_1, \ldots, x_8\}$ be a set of representatives for them.  Then $\mathrm{Inn}(D_8)$ is a set of maps, with each map being given as conjugation by one of the $x_i$.

Comment: Finding $\mathrm{Out}(D_8)$ is just a touch trickier.  You just have to find one automorphism $\phi$ which is not in $\mathrm{Inn}(D_8)$.  Once you have it $\mathrm{Out}(D_8)$ are the cosets $\{\mathrm{Inn}(D_8), \phi\mathrm{Inn}(D_8)\}$.