# Inner and Outer automorphism

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi_g$ be the inner automorphism defined by $\phi_g(x) = gxg^{-1}$ for all $x$ in $G$. Let $a$ in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$, show that a $\phi_g (a^{-1}) =\phi a(g)$. Why is $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ a normal subgroup of $\mathrm{Au}t(G)$.

$\mathrm{Out}(G)=\mathrm{Aut}(G)/\mathrm{Inn}(G)$. Compute $\mathrm{Inn}(D_8)$ and $\mathrm{Out}(D_8)$?

Comment: I edited your question. Please check and make sure that I didn't change what you are trying to ask. I wasn't sure what you meant by $\phi a$.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: The last part about $D_8$ is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461504/find-the-inner-and-outermorphisms-of-a-particular-dihedral-group/461508#461508

Comment: Your question at the end of your first line seems to be missing something" show that..." **what**? What is $\,\phi\,$ ? Should that be $\,a\phi_ga=\phi_{a(g)}\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\begin{align*}\forall\,x\in G\;,\;\;a\circ\phi_g\circ a^{-1}(x)&=a\left(\phi_g(a^{-1}(x))\right):=a\left(ga^{-1}(x)g^{-1}\right)\\
\phi_{a(g)}(x)&=a(g)x(a(g))^{-1}=a(g)xa(g^{-1})\end{align*}$$

Well, now just show the two rightmost sides above are just the same...

Your second question gets immediately answered  once you *really* understand what you did in (1).